# Java Generic issue: cannot cast Map<K,V> to M extends Map<K, V>

Tags: java, generics, generic-collections

While trying to write some Generic code I faced an issue. Of course, I found some workarounds, but still, why the code below is not working?

```
private static <K, U, M extends Map<K, U>>
Supplier<M> mapSupplier() {
    return  HashMap::new;
}
```

This returns

```
Error:(25, 17) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    no instance(s) of type variable(s) K,V exist so that java.util.HashMap<K,V> conforms to M
```

Update:
This map supplier is needed for me to create custom map collector:

```
public static <E, K, V, M extends Map<K, V>>
Collector<E, ?, M> collectToHashMapWithRandomMerge(BiConsumer<M, E> accumulator) {
    return Collector.of(mapSupplier(),
            accumulator,
            TjiCollectionUtils.randomMapMerger());
}
```

Calling **Collector.of** with **HashMap::new** also causes the same compilation error

Ideally, I don't want to create additional method params and just use the following:

```
  public static <E, K, V, M extends Map<K, V>>
Collector<E, ?, M> collectToHashMapWithRandomMerge(BiConsumer<M, E> accumulator) {
    return Collector.of(HashMap::new,
            accumulator,
            TjiCollectionUtils.randomMapMerger());
}
```

**Answer**
I ended up making:

```
public static <E, K, V>
Collector<E, ?, Map<K, V>> collectToMapWithRandomMerge(BiConsumer<Map<K, V>, E> accumulator) {
    return Collector.of(HashMap::new,
            accumulator,
            TjiCollectionUtils.randomMapMerger());
}
```

And it's called in the following way:

```
MyCollectionUtils.collectToMapWithRandomMerge(
    (Map<String,Integer> m, SomeClassToExtractFrom e) -> ...);
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this code fragment?

Comment: I could potentially provide a more helpful answer if you showed the context under which `mapSupplier` is called.

Comment: It's not working because the caller would have legitimacy to call `SortedMap<A, B> map = mapSupplier();` and yet mapSupplier() fails to build a SortedMap, it build a HashMap instead.

Comment: You pass in a map supplier as a parameter to `collectToHashMapWithRandomMerge`. Why not use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a common misconception of generics, which is that the callee decides what types the generic parameters are. In fact, the *caller* does.

Whoever calls `mapSupplier` gets to decide what `K`, `U` and `M` are. Let's say that I am calling it, and I want `K` to be `Integer`, `U` to be `String`, and `M` to be `Hashtable<Integer, String>`. This is valid because `Hashtable` implements `Map`.

```
Supplier<Hashtable<Integer, String>> htSupplier = mapSupplier();
Hashtable<Integer, String> ht = htSupplier.get();
```

As the caller, I would expect the above to work, but `htSupplier.get`, with your implementation, would actually give me a `HashMap<Integer, String>`, which is an unrelated type to `Hashtable` (in terms of inheritance hierarchy).

In other words, `mapSupplier` has single-handedly decided that `M` should be `HashMap<K, U>` while also saying that it will work on any `M` that implements `Map<K, U>`.

Whenever you see yourself writing a "generic" method that decides what its generic parameters are, that method probably shouldn't have that generic parameter. Therefore, `mapSupplier` should be probably be rewritten without the `M` parameter:

```
private static <K, U>
Supplier<HashMap<K, U>> mapSupplier() {
    return  HashMap::new;
}
```

EDIT:

Seeing the caller, I think you can either:

- remove `M` from `collectToHashMapWithRandomMerge` as well, or:
- make `collectToHashMapWithRandomMerge` accept a `Supplier<M>`, so that *its* caller can decide the type of map.

Comment: @Sweeper, answer please, can it be written as `private static <K, U>
  Supplier<? extends HashMap<K, U>> mapSupplier() {
    return  HashMap::new;
  }` ?

Answer (score 2):

`M extends Map<K, V>` means a *specific* class that extends `Map`. `HashMap` is a class that extends `Map`, but `M` could be, say, `LinkedHashMap`; a `HashMap` isn't a `LinkedHashMap`.

You appear already to be given a `Supplier<M>`, as a parameter:

```
public static <E, K, V, M extends Map<K, V>>
Collector<E, ?, M> collectToHashMapWithRandomMerge(Supplier<M> mapSupplier /* HERE */, BiConsumer<M, E> accumulator) {
    return Collector.of(mapSupplier(),
            accumulator,
            TjiCollectionUtils.randomMapMerger());
}
```

So, just use `mapSupplier` (the parameter) instead of `mapSupplier()` (the result of invoking the method).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was just a typo: obviously, I don't want for the method to have extra parameter =)